# the framework does not load the DLL from the correct path

Tags: c#, asp.net

My .Net 4.0 project consists in several projects.

My starting project is the one on the screenshot.
It displays Default.aspx .

Into this project properties, it is set to build into "bin\Debug\" (default behaviour) and it does build the dll there as intended.

However, for any reason, when I run the app, the framework looks for the DLL into "/bin" instead of "bin\Debug\"!!!

I tried to change the build path to "bin\Debug2\" as a test and the same happens. The DLL is created into the correct directory that I set but when I run the app, it tries to load into  "/bin/".

I suppose one of my files is mis-setupped but I have no idea which one.
Any help appreciated.
[image]

Comment: You should not forget to place the screenshot if you refer to one ;p

Comment: For web applications the Output Path should be bin\ by default rather than bin\[configuration] for all configurations, and should not generally be changed as ASP.Net always loads binaries from the bin folder (or GAC).